# Facebook not loading meta or link tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails, title, meta-tags

Facebook isn't showing the title, description or thumbnail when like button is clicked. Thanks for the help!

in head:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.rockomole.com/2012/blog/2012/may/03.jpg" />
<meta name="description" content="TEST PILOT: description">
<meta name="title" content="TEST PILOT: title">
```

[Link](http://www.rockomole.com/2012/blog/2012/may/03.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add proper OG headers for Facebook to work correctly, you can get all the information here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol

In order for you to get started add the following headers on your page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TEST PILOT: test"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="[YOUR URL]"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="TEST PILOT: description"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rockomole.com/2012/blog/2012/may/03.jpg"/>
```